# How to create new paragraph in determinate position with Apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to insert new paragraphs in diferents positiins in docx.

My code insert new paragraph but not in determinate position

```
XWFParagraph. 
para=docx.createParagraph();

XWPFRun run =para.createRun();

run.setText("example 
 paragraph");
```

Comment: Your current code will always put the new paragraphs at the end. Why not try with https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#insertNewParagraph-org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor- ?